# LARAVEL ORM : select distinct by DATE for each user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

i have a table called visitors  :

```
visitors : (id , user_id , ip  , created_at , route , refer )
```

i store a row for each page visit in the middleware wrapping my links

i want to show these in my admin panel but s you imagine there are a lot of them , so i want to show first visit of each day for each user like if i have this in db

```
1 , 356 , 127.0.0.1 , 2017-08-30 22:41:49
1 , 356 , 127.0.0.1 , 2017-08-30 22:50:49
1 , 356 , 127.0.0.1 , 2017-08-30 22:53:49
1 , 356 , 127.0.0.1 , 2017-08-30 23:11:49
1 , 400 , 127.0.0.1 , 2017-08-30 23:50:49
```

the query result should be

```
1 , 356 , 127.0.0.1 , 2017-08-30 22:41:49
1 , 356 , 127.0.0.1 , 2017-08-30 23:11:49
1 , 400 , 127.0.0.1 , 2017-08-30 23:50:49
```

so what i want is something like

```
DISTINCT(DATE(created_at))
```

but this will effect all users .. i want it to effect each user

its very complicated im not sure how should i go about this

Comment: Look into `MIN` and `GROUP BY`. No `DISTINCT` needed

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 DB::table('visitors')->select('id','user_id','ip','created_at')->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

This will give unique users in a day.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can try this way:

```
DB::table('visitors')
   ->distinct('created_at')
   ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
   ->get();
```

Another way is to have additional field for `User` entity like `fisrt_visit` if it's important

Comment: thanx but this will no factor in users basically just gives first visit of they  , adding another field for first visit would be plan B

Comment: @hretic So you can use `distinct` or `min` and `group by` queries for it

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you want to use the `MIN` function to get the first time they logged in, with `GROUP BY` to group it by the user id:

```
DB::table('visitors')
    ->select(['user_id', DB::raw('MIN(created_at)')])
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->get();
```

You can add in the other columns if you want, but the key is `DB::raw('MIN(created_at)')` which will get the earliest created_at timestamp for each user. The `DB::raw` will pass in that string exactly as you specify.

Comment: thnx , but as i said i want earliest  created_at in each day for each user .. i think this will give me earliest created_at regardless of day or am i mistaking ?

Comment: It was for overall. If you want just the current date, then add `->whereRaw('created_at >= CURDATE()')`, so it will get the first login of any user that had logged in that day.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want every single day, then add another groupBy `->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))`